# If a resolution $f:Y\to X$ satisfies $R^if_*\omega_Y=0$ and $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_Y=0$ for all $i>0$, then do we have $f_*\omega_Y=\omega_X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-functors, projective-schemes, birational-geometry, cohen-macaulay

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety over an algebraically closed field of arbitrary characteristic (but I'm mainly interested in positive characteristic). Assume that $X$ has rational singularities, which by definition shall mean that there exists a resolution of singularities $f:Y\to X$ such that for all $i>0$ we have $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_Y=0$ and $R^if_*\omega_Y=0$. Then is it true that $f_*\omega_Y=\omega_X$, i.e. the trace is an isomorphism?

I can envision a proof when $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay: let $\mathcal{L}$ be an arbitrary line bundle on $X$. By the vanishing of $R^if_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ and the projection formula we obtain that
$$
H^d(X,\mathcal{L}^{-1})\cong H^d(Y,f^*\mathcal{L}^{-1})
$$
where $d=\dim X$. As $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay (and $Y$ is regular), applying Serre-duality on both sides yields
$$
H^0(X,\omega_X\otimes\mathcal{L})\cong H^0(Y,\omega_Y\otimes f^*\mathcal{L}).
$$
Now from the vanishing of $R^if_*\omega_Y$ and the projection formula we may conclude $H^0(Y,\omega_Y\otimes f^*\mathcal{L})\cong H^0(X,f_*\omega_Y\otimes \mathcal{L})$, and as $\mathcal{L}$ was arbitrary we obtain indeed $\omega_X= f_*\omega_Y$.

Now it seems to be well known that rational singularities are Cohen-Macaulay, but every proof I saw is either in characteristic $0$ (where one may use Kodaira vanishing), or already starts with $\omega_X\cong Rf_*\omega_Y$ in the derived category, which as far as I understand already relies on $\omega_X\cong f_*\omega_Y$. What am I missing? I guess I'm just very confused, the material is very new to me.

**Edit:** I think I found a proof now:

We have the isomorphism $Rf_*\mathcal{O}_Y\cong\mathcal{O}_X$ by definition. Now applying $R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(-,\omega_X^{\bullet})$ to both sides, we find
$$
R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(Rf_*\mathcal{O}_Y,\omega_X^{\bullet})\cong \underbrace{R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{O}_X,\omega_X^{\bullet})}_{\cong\omega_X^{\bullet}}.
$$
The LHS can then be written as
$$R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(Rf_*\mathcal{O}_Y,\omega_X^{\bullet})\cong Rf_* R\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{O}_Y,\underbrace{f^{!}\omega_X^{\bullet}}_{\cong\omega_Y})\cong Rf_*\omega_Y.$$

Hence we obtain $Rf_*\omega_Y\cong \omega_X^{\bullet}$, which by the vanishing of $R^i f_*\omega_Y$ implies that $X$ is Cohen Macaulay and also $f_*\omega_Y\cong \omega_X$.

Is this proof correct? And if yes, can we conclude that the trace is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Aizenbud and Avni's *Representation Growth and Rational Singularities of the Moduli Space of Local Systems* ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0371v2.pdf)) collects the following list of equivalent characterizations of rational singularities in appendix B section 7:

> **Proposition B.7.2.** Let $X$ be an algebraic variety (i.e. reduced scheme of finite type over a field). The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ has rational singularities (for one (or equivalently, for some) resolution of singularities $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, the natural morphism $Rp_*(\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}})\to \mathcal{O}_X$ is an isomorphism).
> 2. For any (or equivalently, for some) resolution of singularities $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, the trace map $Tr_p:Rp_*(\omega_{\widetilde{X}})\to \omega_X$ is an isomorphism.
> 3. $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay and for any (or equivalently, for some) resolution of singularities $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, the trace map $Tr_p:Rp_*(\omega_{\widetilde{X}})\to \omega_X$ is an isomorphism.
> 4. $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay and for any (or equivalently, for some) resolution of singularities $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, the trace map $Tr_p:Rp_*(\omega_{\widetilde{X}})\to \omega_X$ is onto.
> 5. $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, normal (or equivalently, regular in codimension one), and for any (or equivalently, for some) resolution of singularities $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$, the morphism $p_*(\omega_X)\to i_*(\omega_{X^{sm}})$ which is the composition of the trace map and the natural isomorphism $\omega_X\to i_*(\omega_{X^{sm}})$ is an isomorphism. Here, $i:X^{sm}\to X$ is the embedding of the regular locus.

This is originally all stated in characteristic zero, but the only part that they need that for is the Grauert-Riemenschneider vanishing theorem used in the equivalence of 2 and 3, which states that if $\pi:X\to Y$ is a proper birational morphism of varieties over $k$, then $R\pi_*\omega_X = \pi_*\omega_X$. This result is now available in arbitrary characteristic, see for instance Chatzistamatiou and Rülling's *Higher Direct Images of the Structure Sheaf in Positive Characteristic* ([arxiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.3599.pdf)).

The proof of the equivalence of 1 and 2, which is what you're interested in, follows either from Elkik's early paper *Singularities rationelles et deformations* (relying on Grauert-Riemenschneider) or from a duality argument (not explained in the paper, but from my recollections, it should look very similar to what you've written here).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the nice references! However, don't you need some extra assumptions on $\pi:X\to Y$ in positive characteristic to conclude $R\pi_*\omega_X=\pi_*\omega_X$? In Chatzistamatiou and Rülling's paper, Theorem 1 concerns only smooth varieties, and Theorem 2 requires the target to be a surjective finite (of degree prime to the characteristic) image of a smooth variety. I don't see how this implies Grauert-Riemenschneider in the generality you are claiming. Is it true that if $f:X\to Y$ with $X$ smooth satisfies $Rf_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$, then $Rf_*\omega_Y=\omega_X$?

Comment: Just checked and darn, it looks like I need to edit this a bit. I've been travelling lately and haven't had as much time as normal - I'll get to it when I can and ping you here once I have.